# LaTeXT installation problem not running setup.exe

Tags: latex

I ma trying to install proTeXt (protext-3.2-031721.zip) in my 64bi-windows laptop, when I am trying to run the setup.exe file I am receiving a warning to check a logfile which contains the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "protext-setup.py", line 298, in <module>
  File "protext-setup.py", line 97, in __init__
  File "wx\_controls.pyc", line 494, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Anna

Comment: Any particular reason you want protext? Most tex users install texlive, thus this is best tested and also well maintained. Some windows users also use miktex.

Comment: hmm no any particular reason o be honest! I will switch to TexLive then! Thnaks a lot